# Can't load Facebook Messenger platform on my website

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to install Facebook Messenger platform on my website.
I added the code needed, whitelisted the domain, but it doesn't load.
In Chrome console I get this error message:

> Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/plugins/customerchat.php?app_id=&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FlY4eZXm_YWu.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df686bdd54ed948%26domain%3D4elements4life.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmydomainname.com%252Ff19bba3c7abf9b4%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=0&locale=en_US&page_id=215165435282363&sdk=joey' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://www.facebook.com".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need httpS on your own website

Comment: You are correct, I need httpS and I use httpS in my website. Also I white-listed my domain with the httpS.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have this very same issue.. I have whitelisted my HTTPS.. :( The answer I got from ManyChat was: "It seems to me your MC widget doesn't load due to certain Content Security Policy directive. What I would suggest here is contacting your webmaster to add MC widget to the CSP — that should do the trick, as I see it. Please, try doing so!" My host provider was of no help at all..

Comment: Nope... didn't succeed.